# Converting JAPE Rule to UIMA RUTA

Tags: uima, gate, ruta

Is there any example available to explain how the JAVA code written in RHS part of the JAPE rule can be converted in the UIMA RUTA? Also is there any way to get features of the annotations in RUTA?

Comment: You cannot directly include Java code in UIMA Ruta. However, you can create an analysis engine and execute it in your Ruta code. In many situations like feature assignment, you do not need Java code since the functionality can be directly expressed in Ruta.

Answer (score 1):

Is your question if you can inject annotations (found by other systems) into RUTA before starting the RUTA analysis? So, if that's the question the answer is "yes, that's possible".

You can do something like this:

```
private static createCASAnnotation(Cas cas, MyOwnAnnotation myOwnAnnotation) {
    Type annotationType = cas.getTypeSystem().getType(myOwnAnnotation.getType());
    if (annotationType != null) {
        AnnotationFS casAnnotation = cas.createAnnotation(annotationType, myOwnAnnotation.getTextStart(), myOwnAnnotation.getTextEnd());

        // Also possible to add features / child annotations
        for (MyOwnAnnotation childAnnotation : myOwnAnnotation.getChildAnnotations()) {
            String featureFullName = casAnnotation.getType().getName() + ":" + childAnnotation.getName();
            Feature feature = casAnnotation.getCAS().getTypeSystem().getFeatureByFullName(featureFullName);
            if (feature != null && feature.getRange().isPrimitive() 
                   && "uima.cas.String".equalsIgnoreCase(feature.getRange().getName())) {

                casAnnotation.setStringValue(feature, childAnnotation.getText());

                // Other options for example "uima.cas.Integer" -> casAnnotation.setIntValue(...
            }
            // if not primitive you can also add Annotation type:
            // AnnotationFS childCASAnnotation = createCASAnnotation(...
            // casAnnotation.setFeatureValue(feature, childCASAnnotation);
        }

        cas.addFsToIndexes(casAnnotation);

    } else {
        log.error("invalid type .... or something better");
        // Or throw exception
    }
}
```

The MyOwnAnnotation is an object from your own domain/system and can be something like:

```
class MyAnnotation {
    private final String value;   // or text or fragment ...??
    private final Long startIndex;
    private final Long endIndex; // or use size/length
    private final List<MyAnnotation> childAnnotations;

    // constructor, builder pattern?, getters ....
}
```

Code examples are for demonstrating the concept.

Comment: My question is more towards using the existing features of the annotations such as length, type and so on.

Comment: Can you give an example of the MyOwnAnnotation myOwnAnnotation file here? is it written in Java or some Ruta rules?

Comment: Just a normal java object. I will update the example with that files specified.